# Пагинация на AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

Добрый день. 
Есть массив данных и таблица с `<ng-repeat>`.
Как мне отфильтровать значения, например от 11-го до 20-го,
как делается в пагинации?

Answer (score 1):

Вкратце смысл в том, чтобы использовать два фильтра для массива с данными.

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in data | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize">
```

Фильтр limitTo ограничивает количество элементов размером страницы и это штатный фильтр angular, другой - startFrom - задает стартовую позицию в массиве.

```
app.filter('startFrom', function() {
    return function(input, start) {
        start = +start; //parse to int
        return input.slice(start);
    }
});
```

Пример использования можно посмотреть по ссылке на [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ZzZB/56/), которая приведена в ответе на такой же вопрос [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11582013/4587123).
Кстати, если я не путаю, этот фильтр должен был появиться в одном из свежих реализовать angularjs.